# Node.js Sequelize get native pool

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, pg

I use `Sequelize` and `pg` to make queries to **Postgres**

I've found the way how to get a Sequelize connection

```
sequilize.connectionManager.getConnection()
  .then((connection) => {})
```

Is there any way to get `pool`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option to use pool of connections from Sequelize this way

```
sequelize.connectionManager.getConnection()
  .then((connection) => {
    connection.query('SOME SQL;')
     .then(() => {
       sequilize.connectionManager.releaseConnection(connection);
     })
  })
```

It returns connection from the pool and then connection has to be released